# Node.js error showing await is only valid in async function

Tags: node.js

I am running Node version 12.20.2 and I'm using Hedera SDK (https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/getting-started/create-an-account).  When I run the code below, it throws this error:

> Await is only valid in async functions.

I have tried wrapping the code in async function as per example code below but cannot get it to work:

```
(async () => {
 //coding goes here
})();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Below is the code

```
const {
 Client, 
 PrivateKey, 
 AccountCreateTransaction, 
 AccountBalanceQuery, 
 Hbar 
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");
require("dotenv").config();

//Grab your Hedera testnet account ID and private key from your .env file
const myAccountId = process.env.MY_ACCOUNT_ID;
const myPrivateKey = process.env.MY_PRIVATE_KEY;

// If we weren't able to grab it, we should throw a new error
if (myAccountId == null || myPrivateKey == null ) {
    throw new Error("Environment variables myAccountId and myPrivateKey must be present");
}

// Create our connection to the Hedera network
// The Hedera JS SDK makes this really easy!
const client = Client.forTestnet();

client.setOperator(myAccountId, myPrivateKey);

//Create new keys
const newAccountPrivateKey = PrivateKey.generateED25519(); 
const newAccountPublicKey = newAccountPrivateKey.publicKey;

//Create a new account with 1,000 tinybar starting balance
const newAccount = await new AccountCreateTransaction()
    .setKey(newAccountPublicKey)
    .setInitialBalance(Hbar.fromTinybars(1000))
    .execute(client);

// Get the new account ID
const getReceipt = await newAccount.getReceipt(client);
const newAccountId = getReceipt.accountId;

console.log("The new account ID is: " + newAccountId);

//Verify the account balance
const accountBalance = await new AccountBalanceQuery()
    .setAccountId(newAccountId)
    .execute(client);

console.log("The new account balance is: " + accountBalance.hbars.toTinybars() + " tinybar.");
```

Comment: so that error disappeared? any new errors?

Comment: (1) Can you place the full stack trace of your exception in the question?   (2) Can you put the source code line number in a comment of at least one line of source code posted in the question so we can determine which line in the stack trace matches?

Comment: The error points to this line of code `const newAccount = await new AccountCreateTransaction()`

Comment: what does the stacktrace say

Comment: I just attach the screenshot in the post showing the errors being displayed

Comment: hm you got this when wrapped inside an async function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `await` expression outside of an `async` function , so try use thing like this

```js
(async () => {
code....
})();
```